# How do I put some code into multiple namespaces without duplicating this code?

Tags: c++, namespaces, code-duplication

Assume I have the method defined in the two different namespaces:

```cpp
namespace foo
{
    void print()
    {
        //do work...
    }
}

namespace bar
{
    void print()
    {
        //do work...
    }
}
```

The `foo::print()` and the `bar::print()` functions are *absolutely* equal. My project uses the numerous calls of these functions.

Is there a way to remove one of the `print()` definitions **without changing the calls of these function**? I mean something like the following (of course, C++ language doesn't allow this construction, **it's just an example**):

```cpp
namespace foo, bar  //wrong code!
{
    void print()
    {
        //do work...
    }
}
```

If there is no way to refactor the code as I want, please tell me, do you like the following decision? Will you be glad if *your* project contains such code? :)

```cpp
namespace foo
{
    void print()
    {
        //do work...
    }
}

namespace bar
{
    void print()
    {
        foo::print();
    }
}
```

**ADD:**

Thank you guys, I'm fully satisfied by your answers. Just one moment I want you to clarify: is there a difference between `using ::foo::print` and `using foo::print`?

Comment: I can understand why you would unaccept my answer, but only if you meant to accept Haroogan's answer.

Comment: Damn, I just clicked on the wrong space. Excuse me, please. I like both your answers but I'll choose Agentlien... just because his reputation is lower :)
Anyway I don't know how to handle the situations then several users give the same right answer during the short time. So, Haroogan, I hope you are not upset by my decision

Comment: No problem, it's always up to you. I pointed this out just because you've accidentally chosen the wrong answer with downvotes. So, now it's all good. Good luck. `;)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can achieve this with a `using` declaration.

```
namespace foo
{
    void print()
    {
        //do work...
    }
}

namespace bar
{
    using foo::print;
}
```

**EDIT**

Regarding the difference between `::foo::print` and `foo::print`: prepending a qualified name with :: means that you explicitly refer to the one in the global namespace. This can be used to select the global one, even if there is another item with the same name closer in scope.

Answer (score 14):

How about `using` declaration:

```
namespace foo
{
    void print()
    {
        // do work ...
    }
}

namespace bar
{
    using ::foo::print;
}
```

Using `::foo::print` instead of `foo::print` is an important point. If you would have another `foo` inside of `bar`:

```
namespace foo
{
    void print()
    {
        // 1 ...
    }
}

namespace bar
{
    namespace foo
    {
        void print()
        {
            // 2 ...
        }
    }

    using   foo::print; // refers to 2
    using ::foo::print; // refers to 1
}
```

then you'd see the merit of using `::`. To summarize, prepending `::` is a safe way to ensure that another nested namespace `foo`, which could be potentially added in future, will not bring you any surprises.

Comment: The tip about :: is good, as long as we can assume `foo` actually is in global namespace.

Answer (score 4):

With a `using` declaration:

```
namespace bar
{
    using ::foo::print;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution is this:

```
namespace foo
{
    void print()
    {
        //do work...
    }
}

namespace bar
{
    void print()
    {
        foo::print();
    }
}
```

However you can write:

```
namespace foo
{
    void print()
    {
        //do work...
    }
}

namespace bar
{
    void print()
    {
        //do work...
    }
}
```

This is not recomended, but there is no evil. Compilers are smart enough to understand that these two functions are the same and can be used the same assembly code.

Remember, `namespace` keyword is for programmers, compiler doesn't care about them very much, for compiler namespaces are like prefix for functions/methods/classes.

Answer (score -2):

**Sample**

```
namespace Q {
    namespace V {
        void f(); // enclosing namespaces are the global namespace, Q, and Q::V
        class C { void m(); };
        }
        void V::f() { // enclosing namespaces are the global namespace, Q, and Q::V
        extern void h(); // ... so this declares Q::V::h
        }
        void V::C::m() { // enclosing namespaces are the global namespace, Q, and Q::V
    }
}
```

Comment: if it wasnt that obvious where this was copied from one could think this is an attempt of fraud.

Comment: btw code only answers are bad, but stolen code only answers are really really bad