# How do I put several functions into multiple namespaces without duplicating this code?

Tags: c++, namespaces, backwards-compatibility

This is a followup to:

[How do I put some code into multiple namespaces without duplicating this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20836622/how-do-i-put-some-code-into-multiple-namespaces-without-duplicating-this-code)

I need to change the name of a namespace but want to keep backwards compatibility. The above solution suggests that I would have to do what is done there for each and every function:

```
namespace NewNamespaceName
{
        void print()
        {
                //do work...
        }
        // 50 other functions
}

namespace OldNameSpaceName
{
        using NewNamespaceName::print;
        // 50 other using declarations
}
```

My question: Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Put all in a unique namespace, and `using` the full namespace (probably `inline`).

Comment: If you have symbols in `NewNamespaceName` that should *not* be in `OldNamespaceName` then no you have no other choice. Possibly you could automate it with a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do

```
namespace NewNamespaceName
{
        void print()
        {
                //do work...
        }
        // 50 other functions
}

namespace OldNameSpaceName
{
        using namespace NewNamespaceName;
}
```

If `NewNamespaceName` has other things you would want to include, but not want them to be in `OldNamespaceName`, then just make another private namespace and import that into the old namespace

```
namespace NewNamespaceName
{
        namespace Private {
                void print() { ... }
                // 50 other functions
        }
}

namespace OldNameSpaceName
{
        using namespace NewNamespaceName::Private;
}
```

Live example here https://wandbox.org/permlink/taRPm1hAd2FHbAYo

Comment: `Private` should be an `inline` namespace, though, or there should at least be a `using namespace Private;` inside `NewNamespaceName`.

Comment: I like that very much! Can I add `using namespace Private;` within NewNamespaceName? Then all shared functions would be accessible via `NewNamespaceName::print()` and `OldNameSpaceName::print()`, right? Or will `inline namespace Private` do the same thing?

Comment: @Fabian yep! you can do that if you want.  I updated my answer to include this link at the end https://wandbox.org/permlink/taRPm1hAd2FHbAYo, take a look!

Answer (score 6):

Just use a namespace alias:

```
namespace OldNameSpaceName = NewNameSpaceName;
```